# Integral of positive Part

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, definite-integrals

Is $$\int_a^b \big(f(x)\big)^+\mathrm{d}x = \left( \int_a^b f(x) \mathrm{d}x \right)^+$$ provided that $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is integrable? This means, can taking positive part and integration be swapped for nice functions? Here, $(x)^+=\max\{x,0\}$ is the positive part of $x$.

**Edit:**

I see that this formula does not hold in general. What about if $a=0$ and $$f(x)= C e^{-px}-De^{-qx}$$ with $C,D,p,q\in\mathbb{R}$ and $C,D\geq0$. Does the formula hold in this special case?

Comment: For an easy counterexample, consider $f(x)=x$, $a=-1$, and $b=1$.

Comment: @MathIsFun7225 You should consider adding an answer based on what you wrote in your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the best that we can hope for: Note that $(x)^+ = \max\{0, x\}$ is a convex function. Then by the Jensen's inequality, we have

$$ \left( \frac{1}{b-a} \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \right)^+ \leq \frac{1}{b-a} \int_{a}^{b} (f(x))^+ \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

Now using the fact that $x \mapsto (x)^+$ is [*positive homogeneous*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function#Positive_homogeneity), we can cancel out the common factor $\frac{1}{b-a}$ from both sides to get

$$ \left( \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \right)^+ \leq \int_{a}^{b} (f(x))^+ \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

We also note that this inequality can be strict if $f$ takes negative values on a set of positive measure.

Answer (score 3):

Note that

$$\int_0^{2\pi}(\sin x)^+\,dx = \int_0^{\pi}\sin x\,dx =2,$$

while

$$(\int_0^{2\pi}\sin x\,dx)^+ = 0^+ = 0.$$